# How to register lifecycle extension using native Android code in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am implementing Adobe Analytics in my React Native project, and I need to `registerLifecycle` with Mobile Core in native code.

I am adding the onResume and onPause in MainApplication.java but I am getting the following error:

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
 @Override
error: cannot find symbol
  super.onResume();
       ^
  symbol: method onResume()
```

MainApplication.java

```
 @Override  
   public void onResume() {  
      MobileCore.setApplication(this);
      MobileCore.lifecycleStart(null);
   }
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
      MobileCore.lifecyclePause();
   }
```

Comment: add super.onResume() and super.onPause() after your function calls

Answer (score 0):

Because `Application` doesn't contain `onResume()` and `onPause()`. Those methods should be overridden in `Activity` classes